# using abstract classes from another assembly in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have 3 projects:

```
1 Web Project which is in .NET MVC3
2 Buisness Logic for the application. Where it is being referenced from the Web Project.
3 External Project (MyTools) which has some generic functionality like log4Net, nHibernate implementations.
```

My goal is to implement a particular abstract class which is in the MyTools project in the buisness logic.

```
public class Client : IEntity //Project Location: Buisness Logic Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAO : BaseDAO<Client> //Project Location: Buisness Logic Project
{

}

public interface IEntity //Project Location: MyTools Logic Project
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseDAO<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity, new() //Project      Location: MyTools Logic Project
{
    public static TEntity GetEntityById(int Id)
    {
        //Logic here to get object with ID = id
    }
}
```

The problem is here: when I try to use ClientAO class, GetEntityById Method is not available in the web project although it is being referenced. Then if I move all the logic in the MyTools project into the buisness logic without changing anything, GetEntityById will be available. I cannot understand what is happening with this issue. Is there any problem with Access Modifiers? As far as I know setting a class to public, that class can be accessed even from different assembly.

Thanks

Comment: I just put this code in separate projects, and could access `GetEntityById()` from the `ClientAO` class.  Are both your projects targeting the same version of the .NET framework?  Are you getting build errors or runtime exceptions?

Comment: did you add the proper references to the business logic project?

Comment: This is very strange - Logically it should work - Don't know what to do.

Comment: If you create 2 new projects and copy/paste that code above into the respective projects, does it build?  It should, which means your issue probably doesn't lie in the code you posted.

Comment: Problem solved. My mistake as stated by m4tt1mus - Reference problem - Thats what caused the problem.

Comment: It's always the obvious things staring us right in the face that are the hardest things to find. :)

Comment: Glad i could help. My one question was something obvious too! lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proper references are added to your business logic project, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

GetEntityById is a static method.  Perhaps the first time you're trying to use that method an instance of ClientDAO , and the 2nd time you tried using the class ?

Anyway, why is that method static ?

Comment: I am trying to use it like this: ClientAO.GetEntityById(5); But GetEntityById is not available when the abstract class is located in a different project.

Comment: Does BaseDAO<Client>.GetEntityById(5) work? It doesn't really make sense to call statics from a derived class.